# Distribution of a function of uniform random variables

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let U, V and W be i.i.d. random variables with uniform distribution on [0,1]. Find the distribution of (U*V)^W.

I tried conditioning on the values of V and W to get a double integral over the unit square but I ended up having to integrate 1/v from 0 to 1 which is clearly wrong.

Comment: I think I know where your trouble is coming in getting the $1/v$, and there is a simple fix, but can you show your work so I can see exactly what you are doing?

Comment: looks uniform to me

Comment: 1. This was asked before on the site. 2. Indeed the result is uniform on (0,1). 3. Standard methods work here. 4. You do not show what you did so how can we help?

Comment: @Did: Slightly in OP's defense, it sounds like OP is trying to evaluate:

$$P((UV)^W\leq x)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^{x^{1/w}/v}dudvdw,$$

which is a somewhat different approach from the answers in the duplicate question.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I tried doing